# Login to super user for running script

Tags: permissions, scripting, users

I have `sample.sh` script in `/u01/dump` location. I'm running it from root.

My requirement is while running the `sample.sh` script it has to be login as oracle1 user using SU (super user) and display all files in `/u02/dba/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

So I suggest using:

`su -l oracle1`

Answer (score 1):

It may be dirty hack but it will work :)

Modify `/etc/passwd` file by replacing `/bin/sh` tag of oracle1 user to `ls` and it's home directory to `/u02/dba`
Also use `su -l oracle1` in your `sample.sh` script.

So that, whenever you run script, the point where you changing user, it will show list of it's home directory.

Comment: I liked that actually.. love those dirty hacks when they work :D